# Dice statistics in Python

Tags: python, statistics, dice

: Repeatedly asks the user for the number of times to roll the dice, quitting only when the user-entered number is less than 1. Hint: Use a while loop that will execute as long as num_rolls is greater than or equal to 1.

I did this but don't know how to do it using while loop.

```
import random

num_sixes = 0
num_sevens = 0
num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))

if num_rolls >= 1:
for i in range(num_rolls):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll_total = die1 + die2

    #Count number of sixes and sevens
    if roll_total == 6:
        num_sixes = num_sixes + 1
    if roll_total == 7:
        num_sevens = num_sevens + 1
    print('Roll %d is %d (%d + %d)' % (i, roll_total, die1, die2))

print('\nDice roll statistics:')
print('6s:', num_sixes)
print('7s:', num_sevens)
else:
print('Invalid number of rolls. Try again.')
*
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a `while` loop is a very common way to solve some problems in programming languages like C. In Python you can do that as well, but Python  has it's own ways to do some things. In your case you have been using a `for` loop with the `range()` function. That is more "pythonic" than counting down with `while`, which is more "C-ish".

Interestingly, the `range` function is clever and you non't need to do an extra check. Any integer argument `< 1` will result in an empty list and the `for` loop will not be executed. And the `for` has an `else`:

```
for i in range(num_rolls):
    # your dicing code
else:
    print('Invalid number of rolls. Exiting.')
    sys.exit(1) # might be good to signal an error with a return code > 0

# your result printing code
```

**TL;DR:** Your code is fine if not better. Only change it if the teacher (?) requires `while`.

Comment: This is all good advice in general… but it's wrong for this question. "Repeatedly asks the user for the number of times to roll the dice, quitting only when the user-entered number is less than 1." That requires an outer loop, around his inner loop.

Comment: (Of course using `while num_rolls >= 1:` and repeating the `input` at the end of the loop, which is what I suspect his teacher wants, is _also_ not Pythonic… but it's not nearly as bad as replacing his `for` loop with a `while` loop would be.)